# I want to remove negative part from graph using CorePlot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, graph, core-plot

I implement the core plot library in my application i want to remove the negative part from my graph i search a lot on google but can not find any answer. The negative values on graph is shown when i scroll down the graph and also shown i scroll to left.
Here is my code

```
-(void)drawGraph{

    graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];

    CPTTheme *theme = [CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme];
    [graph applyTheme:theme];

    hostingView1 = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    hostingView1.hostedGraph = graph;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568){
        hostingView1.frame = CGRectMake(15, 5, 290, 220);
    }
    else{
    hostingView1.frame = CGRectMake(15, 3, 290, 135);
    }
    [myGraphView addSubview:hostingView1];
    [myGraphView addSubview:lbl1];
    [myGraphView addSubview:lbl2];

    [lbl1 setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI / 2)];
    [hostingView1 release];


    graph.paddingLeft = 0;
    graph.paddingTop = 0;
    graph.paddingRight = 0;
    graph.paddingBottom = 0;

    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 35.0 ;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingTop = 20.0 ;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingRight = 5.0 ;
    graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingBottom = 30 ;

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;

    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(50.0)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(10.0)];

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) graph.axisSet ;
    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis ;
    x. minorTickLineStyle = nil ;

    x. majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString (@"10");

    x. orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString ( @"0" );

    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis ;

    y. minorTickLineStyle = nil ;

    y. majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromString ( @"2" );

    y. orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString (@"0");

    dataSourceLinePlot = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"Green Plot";

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [[dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];
    lineStyle.lineWidth = 0.3f;
    lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor orangeColor];
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

    dataSourceLinePlot.opacity = 0.0f;

    dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;
    [graph addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];

    CPTGradient *areaGradient = [ CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor :[CPTColor orangeColor] endingColor :[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.55 green:0.55 blue:0.16 alpha:0.0]];

    areaGradient.angle = -00.0f ;

    CPTFill *areaGradientFill = [ CPTFill fillWithGradient :areaGradient];

    dataSourceLinePlot. areaFill = areaGradientFill;
    dataSourceLinePlot. areaBaseValue = CPTDecimalFromString ( @"0.0" );
    dataSourceLinePlot.interpolation = CPTScatterPlotInterpolationLinear ;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the View/object handling the graph adopt the CPTPlotSpaceDelegate protocol:

```
@interface YourViewController () <CPTPlotSpaceDelegate>
```

Then assign the controller to the plotspace's delegate:

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
[plotSpace setDelegate:self];
```

Finally, have the controller implement the CPTPlotSpaceDelegate function "willChangePlotRangeTo"

```
-(CPTPlotRange*)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    if([newRange locationDouble] < 0)
    {
        if(coordinate == CPTCoordinateX)
            return  [(CPTXYPlotSpace*)space xRange];
        else if(coordinate == CPTCoordinateY)
            return [(CPTXYPlotSpace*)space yRange];
    }
    return newRange;
}
```

This prevents the plot space from scrolling any further by returning the current plot range.  You can declare whatever lower boundary you'd like if you should decide it needs to change for either axis.